Add Options Dynamically in Choice Attribute
I want to fetch some options from an external API and then put those options in an attribute (datatype is choice) in a custom table (in Power Apps).
Fetching options from external API is not a problem, it is working fine. I'm not sure how to add these options in that attribute via Cloud Flow/PowerAutomate?
Note: I don't want to add these options manually.

External API is https://myclient.com/b2bapi/options/city

Response from external API will be:
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Delhi",
            "id": 1412
        },
        {
            "name": "Jaipur",
            "id": 1553
        },
        {
            "name": "Bhopal",
            "id": 1414
        },
        {
            "name": "Hyderabad",
            "id": 1537
        },
        {
            "name": "Surat",
            "id": 1411
        }
  ]
}


Add these city options in 'EmpCity' attribute via Cloud Flow/PowerAutomate.
PowerApps column screenshot - Dropdown values example



I want to achieve this via Cloud Flow/PowerAutomate. If this is not possible via Cloud Flow, how can I achieve this?

this is in a dataverse table correct?

I would be very cautious in having an api update/reset your column schema. What if the numbers change? What will happen to your exiting table rows with the old values?

@iBeMeltin, affirmative, this will be a dataverse table.

@SamNseir, Thanks for the new angle. Let's assume that we will only add new dropdowns, will not remove existing ones. Also, I'll keep this scheduled - to run once in a week and sync the dropdown options.
